# How to extract select columns from a sqlite database with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to write. code that will allow a user to select specific columns from a sqlite database which will then be transformed into a pandas data frame.  I am using a test database titled `test_database.db` with a table titled `test`.  The table has three columns, `id`, `value_one`, and `value_two`.  The function I am showing exists within a class that establishes a connection to the database and in this function the user only needs to pass the table name and a list of columns that they would like to extract.  For instance in command line sqlite I might type the command `select value_one, value_two from test` if I wanted only to read in the columns `value_one` and `column_two` from the table `test`.  If I type this command into command line the method works.  However, in this case I use python to build the text string which is fed into pandas.read_sql_query() and the method does not work.  My code is shown below

```
class ReadSQL:
    def __init__(self, database):
        self.database = database
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(self.database)
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

    def query_columns_to_dataframe(table, columns):
        query = 'select '
        for i in range(len(columns)):
            query = query + columns[I] + ', '
        query = query[:-2] + ' from ' + table
        # print(query)
        df = pd.read_sql_query(query, self.conn)
        return

    def close_database()
        self.conn.close
        return

test = ReadSQL(test_database.db)
df = query_columns_to_dataframe('test', ['value_one', 'value_two'])
```

I am assuming my problem has something to do with the way that `query_columns_to_dataframe()` pre-processes the information because if I uncomment the `print` command in `query_columnes_to_dataframe()` I get a text string that looks identical to what works if I just type it directly into command line.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mopped up a few mistakes in your code to produce this, which works. Note that I inadvertently changed the names of the fields in your test db.

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

class ReadSQL:
    def __init__(self, database):
        self.database = database
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(self.database)
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

    def query_columns_to_dataframe(self, table, columns):
        query = 'select '
        for i in range(len(columns)):
            query = query + columns[i] + ', '
        query = query[:-2] + ' from ' + table
        #~ print(query)
        df = pd.read_sql_query(query, self.conn)
        return df

    def close_database():
        self.conn.close
        return

test = ReadSQL('test_database.db')
df = test.query_columns_to_dataframe('test', ['value_1', 'value_2'])
print (df)
```

Output:

```
   value_1  value_2
0        2        3
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code are full of syntax errors and issues

1. The `return` in `query_columns_to_dataframe` should be `return df`. This is the primary reason why your code does not return anything.
2. `self.cur` is not used
3. Missing self parameter when declaring `query_columns_to_dataframe`
4. Missing colon at the end of the line `def close_database()`
5. Missing self parameter when declaring `close_database`
6. Missing parentheses here: `self.conn.close`
7. This `df = query_columns_to_dataframe` should be `df = test.query_columns_to_dataframe`

Fixing these errors and your code should work.

Comment: My apologies, the code I presented on stack overflow was a quickly written example from the larger code.  Only one of the syntax errors that you correctly found are in the actual code.